error con el getHeader
al momento de hacer el insert no me ingresa un valor, agregue un dd para ver y me sale lo siguiente
b"PeriodoCampaña" => "202403"
no se porque sale esa b
 public function csv(Request $request)
    {
        $archivo = $request->file('archivo');

        $csv = Reader::createFromPath($archivo->getPathname(), 'r');
        $csv->setDelimiter(';');
        $csv->setHeaderOffset(0);
        set_time_limit(300);

        try {
            Paso_EFE_C18Consumo::unsetEventDispatcher(); // Desactivar eventos

            DB::beginTransaction();

            // Truncar la tabla
            DB::table('Paso_EFE_C18Consumo')->truncate();

            // Obtener los encabezados y reemplazar espacios por guiones bajos
            // Obtener los encabezados y eliminar el prefijo 'b'
        $encabezados = $csv->getHeader();


// Iterar sobre las filas y realizar las transformaciones necesarias
            foreach ($csv as $fila) {
    // Convertir los valores a una codificación compatible (por ejemplo, UTF-8)
    $fila = array_map('utf8_encode', $fila);

    // Eliminar el prefijo 'b' de PeriodoCampaña
    $fila['PeriodoCampaña'] = str_replace('b', '', $fila['PeriodoCampaña']);

    // Reemplazar comas por puntos en los valores numéricos
    foreach ($fila as $clave => $valor) {
        if ($clave === 'ComisionRL' || $clave === 'PorcentVta') {
            $fila[$clave] = str_replace(',', '.', $valor);
        }
    }

    // Convertir la fecha de 'd-m-Y' a 'Y-m-d'
    $fecha_gestion = null;
    if (!empty($fila['Fecha_Gestion'])) {
        $fecha_gestion = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $fila['Fecha_Gestion']);
        $fecha_gestion_formato_sql = $fecha_gestion ? $fecha_gestion->format('Y-m-d') : null;
        $fila['Fecha_Gestion'] = $fecha_gestion_formato_sql;
    }

    Paso_EFE_C18Consumo::create($fila);
}

Estuve viendo y problando quitar el b pero no e podido quitarle entonces no se realiza el insert en mi tabla en sqlserver, agradeceria cualquier dato
